# How to update a Postgres table with a join statement?

Tags: database, postgresql, syntax, left-join, outer-join

I'd like to do something like this:

```
update t1 set t1.column1 = 'changed'
from left outer join t2 on t1.dataid = t2.dataid
where t2.column2 != 'foo';
```

Basically, I need to check something in `t2` when deciding which `t1` records to update. How can I make this syntactically correct?

Comment: There is an example for such an update in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing a LEFT JOIN, it's simpler to establish the correlation to the other table in the WHERE clause, when the values from the correlated table don't have to be transferred to the updated table.

It would look like this:

```
update t1 set t1.column1 = 'changed'
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.dataid = t2.dataid and t2.column2='foo');
```

Comment: This almost works, here is my correction: `update t1 set column1 = 'changed' 
where exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.dataid = t2.dataid and t2.column2 != 'foo');` (removed the `t1.` from the `t1.column1` which was causing an error, and changed the where logic to fit my specific case.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
update t1 
set t1.column1 = 'changed'
from t2
where t1.dataid = t2.dataid
  and t2.column2 != 'foo';
```

If you really need outer join try something like:

```
update t1
set t1.column1 = 'changed'
from (select 1 as dummy) dummy_table
left join t2 on t1.dataid = t2.dataid
            and t2.column2 != 'foo';
```

Havent tested - it may not work.

Another possible way is to do a inner join to a "copy" of `t1` and then do a left join to `t2`

Comment: This will give me an implied `inner join`. I need an `outer join` (I want to affect records that join with a null also).

Comment: @BLuFeNiX I updated my ansver with possible ways to do a left join.

Comment: Just tried and got this error: 

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "t1"
LINE 4: left join t2 on t1.dataid = t2.dataid